# The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

I am upgrading my CRM from 2013 to 2015. I have an SQL instance on a separate server which I connect to from my CRM App server. I am getting the following error hen trying to connect to CRM app serer '***The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database. A connection to the database is required for all requests and processing. (rsReportServerDatabaseUnavailable) Get Online Help
 A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)***

I have tried fixes recommended when I search the web, this is what I tried.

1. I tried enabling TCP/IP and Named Pipes protocols.
2. I assigned permissions to the current logon user and server account(Network Service) running the Report Server Service
3. I assigned 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' as a user in Security --> Login and assigned RsExecRole.
4. I also tried restarting the SQL server with reporting serves installed on it, still no luck.

Please assist. My SQL Server version is 2014, Windows Server 2012r2, CRM Dynamics 2013, moving to 2015.

Comment: Are your SPNs all set up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

From error mentioned, it seems certificate is not from trusted authority. Below is the nearly same question asked previously

[The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615260/the-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-an-authority-that-is-not-trusted-when-conn)