# Getting the following error while connecting to source server for Data Migration in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, data-migration

```
Invalid source server details were specified for the migration.
Validator 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Migration.Core.Validators.SupportedDatabaseEnvironmentValidator' failed to validate data.
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)
The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted
```

[image]

I am new to Azure and want data migration from my computer DB to azure.

Comment: Have you tried different mitigations? For example, what happens with this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615260/the-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-an-authority-that-is-not-trusted-when-conn

Answer (score 10):

The solution i found here is we need to check the second check box(eg.Trust server certificates), and this will works fine for me.