# The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I studied [the help here on upgrading to aspnetcore 2.1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation)

My database is SQLExpress 2016SP1

I am able to add a migration but when I issue

```
update-database
```

at the Package Manager Console, I get an error

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process.
>   (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

The connection string is of the form

```
   Server="Server=myserver;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

The `DbContext` is

```
public class ApiDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApiDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApiDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

The Context Factory is

```
public class MyContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApiDbContext>
{
    public ApiDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApiDbContext>();
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        var config = builder.Build();
        var connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase");
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        return new ApiDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

[Update]

If I hard code the connection string inside the implementation of  IDesignTimeDbContextFactory  then I can run the migrations

```
public class MyContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApiDbContext>
{
    public ApiDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApiDbContext>();
        var connectionString =    "Server=myserver;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        return new ApiDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Hard coding the connection string is not desirable so I would like a better answer.

I am unclear as to why the implementation of  IDesignTimeDbContextFactory is needed.  (my migration does fail without it )

I have updated my Startup.cs and Progam.cs to match those of a newly generated program where the implementation is not needed.

```
 public class Program
 {
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApiDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApiDbContext>();
```

services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();

        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

[Update]

I updated to VS2017 version 15.7.3.
When I went to repeat the problem and create the first migration, PM displayed the message

```
The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional
```

When I marked this file copy always then both the add-migration and the update-database worked.

Comment: You likely don't have a CA-signed certificate installed in your SQL

Comment: @viveknuna I don't need a certificate for a new project so why would I need one for an upgraded project?

Comment: If using Windows Authentication is an option, along with doing what @Will Jones said(setting TrustServerCertificate=True). This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try adding `TrustServerCertificate=True` to the connection string, as per [This StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17658821/9897665)

## 2022 Update:

The linked post has been updated with more up to date recommendations. The answer posted here is a stopgap, and not recommended for production workloads

Comment: Had same error while trying to use SSDT on visual studio. This works.

Comment: also add Encrypt=False; worked for me

Answer (score 8):

Setting "TrustServerCertificate=True" and using Windows Authentication resolved this for me.

Answer (score 1):

changing Encrypt=False; in the connection string worked for me;

Answer (score 0):

```
"Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Bulky;TrustServerCertificate=True;User ID=sa; Password=123;Trusted_Connection=True"
```

replace Password with your selected password and user

Express SQL installed locally