# Import SQL Server data in excel - SSL error

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I need to display data in Excel, from a SQL Server. I am using SQL Server 2017 and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

When I try to connect to the database with Excel, however, through the Data tab -> Get data -> From Database -> From SQL Server database.

I think the error is not in Excel, however, since the error itself is in Dutch. It reads 'The certificate chain has been granted by a non-trusted authority'. I have absolutely no idea why this is the case with my computer. I was thinking that this may be because of my antivirus (BitDefender):

[image: SSL error]

The error reads

> The certificate chain has been granted by a non-trusted authority

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Since this is quite essential.

**Edit/note:** This is different than when logging in with Microsoft Server Studio since I can log in to the server with this. When using excel, however, I can't log in successfully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted" when connecting DB in VM Role from Azure website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615260/the-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-an-authority-that-is-not-trusted-when-conn)

Comment: Have you seen https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/173785/the-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-an-authority-that-is-not-trusted

Comment: @CaiusJard this issue are using EXCEL not using SSMS

Comment: But when you make the connection in excel you can disable certificate check in the connection setup, no? (Add `TrustServerCertificate=True` to the connection string). Of course it's a workaround; we should resolve the certificate issue