# MS Excel Error: “The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted”

Tags: sql-server, excel

I am getting below error with Excel file which is retrieving data from SQL Server.

> DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

Please help!

Comment: Sounds a lot like [“The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted” when connecting DB in VM Role from Azure website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615260/the-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-an-authority-that-is-not-trusted-when-conn).

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted" when connecting DB in VM Role from Azure website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615260/the-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-an-authority-that-is-not-trusted-when-conn)