# Error connecting to SQL Db from Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-vm, linked-service

I can connect to SQL db (which is in a VM on Azure) via SSMS

**Ex:**

```
Server Adress: sqldb.com, 4848
User: admin
Pwd: pwd1234!
```

but when connecting from Azure Data Factory getting below error:

```
Cannot connect to SQL Database: 'sqldb.com,4848', Database: 'xyz', User: 'admin'. 
Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall 
allows the integration runtime to access.
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during 
the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an 
authority that is not trusted.), SqlErrorNumber=-2146893019,Class=20,State=0,
The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted
Activity ID: 16xxff36-xx3a-46d3-ss6a-b6bss9c2ss1a.
```

Any clues?

Comment: is it a typo that there is a tiny dot after `sqldb.com` in the error message?

Comment: @ray: sorry.. i was my typo. doesnt work with sqldb.com,4848

Answer (score 0):

Try changing Trusted_Connection=True; in key vault secret.

Ex connection string (e.g. Server=tcp:.database.windows.net,1433;Database=;User ID=@;Password=;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30).

Refer :
["The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted" when connecting DB in VM Role from Azure website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615260/the-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-an-authority-that-is-not-trusted-when-conn)