# php to mssql server errro SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

Tags: php, sql-server, ssl, sqlsrv

first of all, im really noob.(sorry for that)
secondly, iam trying to connect php to mssql server.
thirdly, i already install sqlsrv, pdo_sqlsrv, and msodbcsql.msi
but still get error message when trying to connect
[image]
[image]

my php version is 8.0.10, x64;
mssql server 2012.

my code in php to test connection :

```
<?php
$serverName = "10.xxx.xx.148";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"zzzz", "UID"=>"ww","PWD"=>"123cccc");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {
 echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));}
?>
```

and then i get error, and instruction to install msodbcsql.msi, i install it just like the instruction. but then show new error that iam unable to solved.

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVtQK.jpg) => -2146893019 [code] => -2146893019 [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuwDV.jpg) => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted. ) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVtQK.jpg) => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVtQK.jpg) => -2146893019 [code] => -2146893019 [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuwDV.jpg) => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection ) )

additional info: when i connect dbeaver (different pc) to mssql server (same server) there is no problem.

thank you in advance

Comment: If you connect to machine external of PHP did you get cert error as well?

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/connect/error-message-when-you-connect) or this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615260/the-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-an-authority-that-is-not-trusted-when-conn)?

Comment: @Zhorov, i tried adding TrustServerCertificate=True, in Additional Connection Parameters. but when i try to connect from php host, the error still occur.

Comment: @user3783243 sorry i dont get what you mean, iam mssql is really a stranger for me

Comment: This behavior is well-documented in the latest major versions of ODBC and JDBC, e.g.: [ODBC Driver 18.0 for SQL Server Released](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228). The available options are shown at [Connection Options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/connection-options). Setting `TrustServerCertificate` to `1` or `True` will accept SQL Server's self-signed certificate. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71709139/edit) your question to show your exact changes if you cannot get it to work.

Comment: Aside... DBeaver probably works because it's using older drivers. The `Encrypt=True` breaking change occurred in ODBC 18 and JDBC 10.2.

Comment: oh my god, im so stupid. i just need add TrustServerCertificate=>true in the php file connectioninfo array.
thank you @AlwaysLearning and all for the help.
am i better deleted this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case anyone is wondering how to define the **TrustServerCertificate** to **1**, this is how i did it, i added the parameter as a new array element as shown below

```
<?php
$serverName = "10.xxx.xx.148";
$connectionInfo = array( 
 "Database"=>"zzzz",
 "UID"=>"ww",
 "PWD"=>"123cccc",
 "TrustServerCertificate"=>true
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I used ODBC Driver 17 instead of ODBC Driver 18 and problem solved. In my case I didn't need encryption so driver 17 was ok for me.

Comment: You are a life saver. Spent with this issue a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

I downgrade from ODBC Driver 18 to ODBC Driver 17.
It's work in Laravel 9 and PHP 8.2