# ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server SSL Provider

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, odbc, driver

Recently upgraded PHP7 to PHP8 and updated Apache version. All PHP scripts connecting to SQL Server now throwing following error:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] =>
> -2146893019 [code] => -2146893019 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an
> authority that is not trusted. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18
> for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an
> authority that is not trusted. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 08001
> [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => -2146893019 [code] => -2146893019 [2] =>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish
> connection [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL
> Server]Client unable to establish connection ) )

ODBC driver is already installed. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

I tried to reinstall ODBC driver to latest version, but no results so far.

Comment: Which driver do you use to connect to the SQL Server instance? Can you post one of your PHP scripts? This [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71709139/php-to-mssql-server-errro-ssl-provider-the-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-an-a) is also a possible solution to your problem.

Comment: Have you read the [ODBC Driver 18.0 for SQL Server Released](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228) notes yet? In particular, read the whole section about _**BREAKING CHANGE** - Default Encrypt to Yes/Mandatory._