# Pyodbc MSSQL connection with self signed certificate in the chain?

Tags: python, sql-server, ssl, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to a MSSQL database; the issue is that on the network where this script is ran, we use a self-signed certificate internally and I think pyodbc is *not* happy with that.

The database I am connecting to (MSSQL) lives outside our network - and when I try to connect to the database by running my script on a server (Windows 2016), I get the following errors:

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.
```

I'm not sure how to get pyodbc to recognize that our self-signed cert is 'to be trusted'.

The connection string looks like this:

```
def get_db_cursor():
    driver = os.environ.get("ODBC_DRIVER") # ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
    host = os.environ.get("db_HOST")
    db_name = os.environ.get("db_NAME")
    db_user = os.environ.get("db_USER")
    db_pass = os.environ.get("db_PASSWORD")
    db_port = os.environ.get("db_PORT")
    connection = pyodbc.connect(
        "DRIVER="
        + driver
        + ";SERVER="
        + host
        + ";PORT="
        + db_port
        + ";DATABASE="
        + db_name
        + ";UID="
        + db_user
        + ";PWD="
        + db_pass
        + ";Encrypt=yes;"
    )
    db_cursor = connection.cursor()
    return db_cursor
```

I use `Encrypt=yes` because it's leaving our network and I'd like it encrypted.

I can use `TrustServerCertificate=True`, but [that is not the correct/safe way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615260/the-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-an-authority-that-is-not-trusted-when-conn) (but it *would* work).

I am curious if anyone knows of or has any other ideas on how to get pyodbc to accept a self-signed cert?

Maybe I'm going about this all wrong - but I just can't seem to get this to not throw that error. All help is appreciated.

Comment: The issue with a self-signed cert is you must trust it, even if it's the a not the correct/safe approach. The correct/safe method is to avoid using a self-signed cert and use one issued by a trusted authority.

Comment: A slightly less bad idea than that might be to import the self-signed cert into Python's list of trusted certificates, wherever that is. But yes, if you have an SQL Server on the global internet you really should have a proper certificate

Comment: I agree with both of you - that using a cert from a trusted authority is ideal. I believe the self-signed cert approach is taken for a network wide security purpose; is there a way to see where Python is looking for that list of trusted certs @Charlieface? So that I might add the self-signed cert to that list?

Comment: It depends on the Python client's host operating system as to where that is. e.g.: when running on Windows 10/11, in the account under which the Python process executes, you'd use the Manage Certificates snap-in to import the self-signed certificate's public key into the user's Trusted Root Certificates store.

Comment: This is one of the worst re-occurring issues I've ever had to face.  Brutally painful to try and get this stuff up and running properly on a mac system.  Updating from 17 to 18 for pyodbc, only to run across issue after issue after issue revolving around this is just, it's unbelievable.

Comment: Yeah @PaulCarlton we recently updated to 18 as well - it's a real pain in the rear with this stuff. We have just gone the route of trusting the server cert - as bad/stupid as that may be. We self-sign certs because we're a very large org - just no way around it with our network. I use a mac as well. If I can help out - let me know.

Comment: @Hanny - thanks for your offer Hanny, I do appreciate it.  I was able to figure out the problem, after a good half day of just walking through each breaking step.  I also work with a larger organization with self signed certs, and it's a pain the ass.  (sys engineers good at this are worth their weight in salt).  OpenSSL on 17 is 1.1 and on 18 it's 3.0.  Because of this, brew/link issues causes the underlying link problems and breaks everything.  When finally upgraded, finally linked properly, it begins to work with added "TrustServerCertificate" params to connection strings.  Sheesh.

Comment: @Hanny - that said, I documented the process in a .md file and its charm is that it's littered with a lots of cuss words. :D. Have a good christmas!