# ASP.NET Core 7.0 error on login: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

I created a simple .NET 7.0 app with SQL Server and if I use the default "localdb" or even after I change it to a "network server", I get the error below:

> The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.

My connection string is:

```
mysqlserver.com;Initial Catalog=db_database;User Id=db_admin;Password=pass123;Persist Security Info=True;Encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=yes
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS: With the above connection string I can scaffold the database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted" when connecting DB in VM Role from Azure website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615260/the-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-an-authority-that-is-not-trusted-when-conn)

Answer (score 11):

This is a breaking change in EF Core 7.0 as noted here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes

You have two options. Option 1: Install a valid certificate on the server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-sql-server-encryption?view=sql-server-ver16

Option 2: You need to add TrustServerCertificate to true or Encrypt=False. The downside with this option is you may leave the server in a potentially insecure state.

Incorrect answer was yes instead of true:

```
mysqlserver.com;Initial Catalog=db_database;User Id=db_admin;Password=pass123;Persist Security Info=True;Encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=yes
```

correct answer:

```
mysqlserver.com;Initial Catalog=db_database;User Id=db_admin;Password=pass123;Persist Security Info=True;Encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=true;
```

Comment: What have you changed?

Comment: @DaleK - The original answer was a copy and paste of the original. I think it was edited to show the difference as an ';' at the end.

Comment: I keep getting : SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

Comment: @dalek  I added some more context to this answer. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The easy fix is to set `Encrypt=False;` Please look at the link in the comment above. I ran across this a while back. A breaking change was introduced in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. While making it more secure by default, the idea is that you now have to implicitly opt into a less secure connection by turning off Encrypt, which in the prior releases defaulted to false, if not set.

Comment: it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you should use TrustServerCertificate=true; instead of yes

Comment: still no luck, even with : TrustServerCertificate=true;    The strange thing is that i can access the database with SSMS, without problems, but not via VS2022.

Comment: @Fillo - Do you mean the client app running in VS or VS?

Comment: Running inside/from Visual Studio Community 2022 with IIS.

Comment: I've a similar issue. Watching with interest. It worked on .net 6 / Efcore 6

Comment: Running into the same issue. I have TrustServerCertificate=True as well as Encrypt=False in my connection string, and I'm still getting the same error on VS2022. SSMS connection works fine.

Answer (score 1):

add

TrustServerCertificate=true

end of ConnectionStrings in appsettings.json like this

"ConnectionStrings": {
"abc": "Data Source = .;Initial Catalog=adsDB;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"

}

Answer (score -1):

This it what worked for me.

**The full Connection string:**

"Server=mysqlserver.com;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User Id=yoursername;Password=yourpassword;Integrated security=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";