# "The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted" after upgrading nuget packages I receive this error

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssl-certificate, .net-7.0

I have multiple API projects and I can them successfully. But the WorkerService API project throws the following warning:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)
```

My connection string:

```
"data source=server ;initial catalog=ECOMDB;persist security info=True;user id=****;password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;"
```

I have seen this post, but it did not solve my issue: ["The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted" when connecting DB in VM Role from Azure website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615260/the-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-an-authority-that-is-not-trusted-when-conn)

Comment: You have `Encrypt=false;TrustServerCertificate=True;` in the presented connection string so shouldn't be getting that error from this. Do you have other connection strings in your appsettings.json file, or hard-coded connection details in your .NET code (especially in Entity Framework migrations)?

Comment: Yes we got this now :) this is the issue . I had double checked many app.config files :) but I notice now there is a additional appsetting.json file this is the missing part thanks a lot your for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       "data source=server ;initial catalog=ECOMDB;persist security info=True;user id=****;password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
    App=EntityFramework;Encrypt=false;TrustServerCertificate=True;"
```

`Encrypt=false;TrustServerCertificate=True;` Added