# Cannot establish a connection between a .Net server and a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api

Long story short I have a problem establishing connection between my Web API .NET application and my SQL Server database, which I use Windows authentication for.

Once I make a request through my API controller in the application, I get back an exception

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090325): The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.

I have seen all threads where people gave advice about setting `Encrypt` to false and `TrustServerCertificate` to true in the connection string but neither of those worked for me.

My current `appsettings.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=LAPTOP-0VDNO79B\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=cv_database;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;"
  }
}
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted" when connecting DB in VM Role from Azure website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615260/the-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-an-authority-that-is-not-trusted-when-conn) Or I guess the answers are the ones you're referring to. Do you have multiple appsettings.json files?

Comment: Have you tried actually using a proper certificate for SQL Server, rather than the builtin self-signed one?

Comment: Are you using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` version 5 or later? The `Encrypt` options changed from bool values `False/True` to a new enumeration `Optional/Mandatory/Strict`.