# What could be causing this error when trying to send data to a database in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-7.0

I am getting this error when trying to send data to database in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy2lB.png)

> SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority which is not trusted.

I also added to my connection string: `TrustServerCertificate=True` and still doesn't work.

I tried adding trustservercertificate, changing tcp ip, running ssms as administrator, restarting it etc.

Comment: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - &#x141;a&#x144;cuch certyfikat&#xF3;w zosta&#x142; wystawiony przez urz&#x105;d, kt&#xF3;rego nie jest zaufany.)

Comment: Could be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615260/the-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-an-authority-that-is-not-trusted-when-conn) please confirm