# Server has been unable to connect in SQL Server Management Studio since it was demoted from domain controller

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Ever since domain controller demotion I was unable to connect to the server itself. It keeps showing this error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - this certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted)

I have tried:

1. Adding `TrustServerCertificate=True` to the connection string
2. Importing and exporting certificates on mmc

Both those option didn't help. Would appreciate any insight.

Comment: If you are getting *"certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted"* then trust server certificate *cannot* be enabled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted" when connecting DB in VM Role from Azure website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615260/the-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-an-authority-that-is-not-trusted-when-conn)

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50504551/2029983), in the linked duplicate candidate, demonstrates how to trust a certificate in SSMS.

Comment: Have you also read the documentation on this [scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/security-considerations-for-a-sql-server-installation?view=sql-server-ver16#Install_DC), and that it's **strongly** recommended against, and if you do then if you change the server to be a member you have to reinstall SQL Server?

Comment: I have tried ticking the "trust server certificate" box before but it still didn't help. However, after reading the documentation you provided it might be the only way to reinstall SQL Server since the domain controller I demoted was the last domain controller.