# Internal connection fatal error when connecting from API

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-8.0

I have multiple .Net projects connecting to my local SQL Server. Everything works except for my API project that throws an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Internal connection fatal error.'

I use my local SQL Server with `Trusted_Connection=True`. I tried to change it to use user id and password like my Winforms and MAUI apps use but I still get same error.

This is my `appsettings.json` file:

```json
{
    "Settings": {
        "devconn-local": "Server =.\\MSSQLSERVER01;Database=myDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True"
    }
}
```

My `Program.cs` file from the API:

```cs
#if DEBUG
    settingname = "Settings:devconn-local";
#endif

string? connstring = builder.Configuration[settingname];

if (connstring == null)
{
    throw new Exception(settingname + " connection string not found");
}

SQLUtility.SetConnectionString(connstring, true);
```

`SQLUtility` class:

```cs
public static void SetConnectionString(string connstring, bool tryopen, string userid = "", string password = "")
{
    ConnectionString = connstring;

    if (userid != "")
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder b = new();
        b.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
        b.UserID = userid;
        b.Password = password;
        ConnectionString = b.ConnectionString;
    }

    if (tryopen)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new(ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open(); // Crashes on this line.
        }
    }
}
```

When I connect to the same `SQLUtility` class from my MAUI and Winforms projects, it connects without an issue.

I'm using .NET 8.0 and SQL Server 2019.

I searched and found a lot of other SO questions on this error but I didn't find any solution.

**Edit**

I reviewed the stack trace and I see the connection to the SQL Server gets passed in correctly but throws an exception

The full exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException
> HResult=0x80131509
> Message=Internal connection fatal error.
> Source=System.Data.SqlClient
> StackTrace:
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.DrainData(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowUnsupportedCollationEncountered(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.GetCodePage(SqlCollation collation, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryProcessEnvChange(Int32 tokenLength, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, SqlEnvChange& sqlEnvChange)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
> at SQLUtility.SetConnectionString(String connstring, Boolean tryopen, String userid, String password) in C:\Users\user\repos\Framework\SQLUtility.cs:line 27
> at Program.$(String[] args) in C:\Users\user\repos\myrepo\Software\API\Program.cs:line 42

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77883323/edit) your question to include the complete error message, including the stack trace, as text. There will be important details in the stack trace that can help determine why the connection is failing. But in all likelyhood it's because the web server isn't configured to pass through the Windows credentials of the requesting user (so it's trying to connect to SQL Server with its own credentials).

Comment: Also, I would recommend to start with minimal reproducible problem. Remove all `if`s and `DEBUG`. Does the code in simplest form connect to DB or not?

Comment: And look in the SQL Server ERRORLOG for corresponding details.

Comment: @Felix The correct connection string gets passed into the procedure, I see it in debug mode that it's using the right connection string.

Comment: Did you notice the `ThrowUnsupportedCollationEncountered` in the stack trace? [SQL Server connectivity issues using Alpine docker images #684](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/684) seems related. Since you're using .NET 8 I'll dare to suggest switching from the deprecated legacy `System.Data.SqlClient` assembly to the modern supported `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` assembly to see if it changes the outcome without changing the environment variables.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks that has solved the original error. I now get a `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)'` error. I will debug it and see why this happens. Or would you know why this will happen?

Comment: Got it https://stackoverflow.com/a/70850834/16019058

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @[AlwaysLearning](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390122/alwayslearning) posted in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77883323/internal-connection-fatal-error-when-connecting-from-api#comment137308868_77883323) the issue was solved by migrating from `System.Data.SqlClient` to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`.

But migrating causes other problems as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17615260/16019058). So I added the `Encrypt=False` to the connection string. Maybe this is not a good idea but because I'm just learning and I use my local server I don't have a problem with this solution.