# when i run dotnet core mvc web api, i get error of SSL certificate

Tags: asp.net-mvc

my error is"Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090325): The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)"

for solve the error i use thid coomand "dotnet dev-certs https --trust" but i can't get solution for my error.

Comment: See this link for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615260/the-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-an-authority-that-is-not-trusted-when-conn